# Highcharts live data update does not work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to js, just copy from official website, the code is:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Charts using Socket.io and Highcharts</title>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js">    </script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        // Create the chart
        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function () {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function () {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                    count: 1,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '1M'
                }, {
                    count: 5,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '5M'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                inputEnabled: false,
                selected: 0
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },

            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function () {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push([
                            time + i * 1000,
                            Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                        ]);
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }]
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

the console told me ‘$’ is not defined, and I have tried to get rid of 'function', getting highcharts error #13. I run it on nodejs, and the code is in index.html file, no other js file.

Comment: Did you add jquery library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before your current script tags:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check this:

https://jsfiddle.net/basmLukr/

Note:  `$(function () {..}` is The jQuery shorter method for the document ready event, so first you need to include jQuery. And I think `Highcharts` creating/updating should be called after page loaded, That's why It didn't work when you got rid of `$(function () {..}` which is "page loaded" function.

Comment: Should be: `add this before your current script tags` :)

Comment: Guys, thanks for your patient to newbie! I have solved this problem.